# No http/https connectivity inside docker container after proxy configuration on Docker client

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-compose, mitmproxy

I followed the [Docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/) of how configurate a proxy for containers. So I put the following in `~/.docker/config.json`

```
{
   (...),
   "proxies":{
      "default":{
         "httpProxy":"http://127.0.0.1:8080",
         "httpsProxy":"http://127.0.0.1:8080",
      }
   }
}
```

And runned

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart docker
```

In the **host**, I started the proxy (mitmproxy) in the `127.0.0.1:8080` address. The proxy looks like is working correctly in the host. However, when I connect **in the container** it seems it could not use the proxy correctly.

```
docker exec -it my_container_1 /bin/bash
```

In the bash:

```
bash-5.0#  wget http://google.com
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

If I use `ping` or some `ftp` address, it works properly, so it's something restricted to the proxy configuration.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` defined in `config.json` are passed by the docker client to the containers. This practically sets the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables in the container. 
Running `echo $http_proxy` in the container will output the value.

Assuming the proxy is configured correctly on the host, the IP address of the proxy should be the IP of the host as seen by the container. 
Replace in `config.json` `127.0.0.1` with the IP of the `docker0` or main network interface (`eth0`) of the host.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing that made it work was to force the proxy to use the host IP and use the host IP in  ~/.docker/config.json too